# How to hide page name in rewrite rules php

Tags: php, .htaccess, hide

I am trying to hide page name from url using rewrite rules in php  but its not working, please see the below example

My url: https://preshop.me/uppages.php?id=abcd1890dx

i want to show like this url: https://preshop.me/abcd1890dx

i am trying with

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$          uppages.php?id=$1 [L]

but not working
Please help me on this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would use
`RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /uppages.php?id=$1 [L]`